# printing list of objects as links in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, object, innerhtml

I am trying to print a list of objects using vanilla javascript. In my loop, only the last item is getting printed. How do I fix this? I tried appending each li to a variable (node) and then append it to my ul id but that did not work. Here is the fiddle:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLgZzw?editors=1011

HTML

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

JS

```
let list = document.getElementById('list');

let obj = {
  "codepen": 'www.codepen.io',
  "jsfiddle": 'www.jsfiddle.com',
  "jsbin": 'www.jsbin.com'
};
function printList(obj){
  for(let key in obj){
    console.log(key);
    list.innerHTML = `<li><a href= ${obj[key]}>${key}</a></li>`;
  }
  //list.appendChild(li);
}
printList(obj);
```

Comment: You need to concatenate your string here `list.innerHTML += `<li><a href= ${obj[key]}>${key}</a></li>`;` using `+=`

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Alien!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concat value to innerHTML.In your case it is always the last value of the iteration that will be set in innerHTML

```js
let list = document.getElementById('list');

let obj = {
  "codepen": 'www.codepen.io',
  "jsfiddle": 'www.jsfiddle.com',
  "jsbin": 'www.jsbin.com'
};

function printList(obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    console.log(key);
    //Changed here. added + before ==.It will concat the current value with previous value
    list.innerHTML += `<li><a href= ${obj[key]}>${key}</a></li>`;
  }
  //list.appendChild(li);
}
printList(obj);
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot @brk